# What is keyword IN for in DNS zone files

Tags: bind

Typical DNS zone files contain records like this:

```
something   IN      A               1.2.3.4
xxxxx       IN      A               2.3.4.5
kkkkk       IN      A               8.2.1.2
```

What is the **IN** for? And why it works even if it's not there?

P.S. yes I did google this, but believe or not googling "in" is not fun.

Comment: The very first Google search result for "DNS IN" links to an identical question on server fault with an answer. Did you *really* bother to search first? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dns+IN  https://serverfault.com/questions/220775/what-does-the-in-mean-in-a-zone-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The field *record class* indicates the namespace of the record information. The most commonly used namespace is that of the Internet, indicated by parameter *IN*, but others exist and are in use, e.g., *CHAOS*.

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file#File_format)